# Adding marker on a leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geodjango

I'm very new to GIS and for learning I started with building a simple web app with GeoDjango. I am using dango-leaflet. Since I have a very limited knowledge I am facing many challenges. I'm trying to put a specifc marker on my map as a test

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import point
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

class Points(gismodels.Model):
      data_lat = 44.915223
     data_long = -93.209741


     @property

     def geom(self):
         return point(self.data_lat, self.data_long, srid=4326)
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

about.html

```
<body>
      <h1> Map  </h1>
     {% leaflet_map "main" callback="main_map_init" %}

      <script type="text/javascript">

          function main_map_init (map, options){

                var dataurl = '{% url "data" %}';

               $.getJSON(dataurl, function(data) {

                      L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
               })
          }
      </script>

</body>
```

I'm having issue with data not being passed on to map. It would be nice if someone could point me to the right direction.